# SpriteKit - How to transition to a new scene with a timer

Tags: swift, timer, sprite-kit, transition, scene

I am currently trying to build a loading scene into my SpriteKit game with my developer logo on it and need to transition to the MainMenuScene after say 5 seconds. How would I go about that.

My code right now looks like this, which is basically just the background/logo image.

```
import SpriteKit

class LoadingScene: SKScene {

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "fatscoprion")
    background.position = CGPoint (x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2)
    background.zPosition = -1
    self.addChild(background)
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you building an actual loading scene, or do you just want to display your logo for 5 seconds?  There is a Launch.xib that you can use.  if that xib is not long enough, you can use your main storyboard to add a view that handles your logo, no need for sprite kit unless it is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a Scheduled Timer and configure a function to call your method that's creates and present the new scene.

Example:

```
class LoadingScene: SKScene {
    var timer = Timer()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "")
        background.position = CGPoint (x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2)
        background.zPosition = -1
        self.addChild(background)
        //Create a Scheduled timer thats will fire a function after the timeInterval
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0,
                                     target: self,
                                     selector: #selector(presentNewScene),
                                     userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    @objc func presentNewScene() {
        //Configure the new scene to be presented and then present.
        let newScene = SKScene(size: .zero)
        view?.presentScene(newScene)
    }

    deinit {
        //Stops the timer.
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend this at all. If you get a call during your loading scene, you are going to run into problems

Comment: If you need to load some resources before making the transition to MainMenuScene, so that's really not the best alternative. It would be best to create a method to load the resources with a completion to make the screen's transition. But if you only need to display a standard screen and hold for 5 sec without any other operation occurring, then the Scheduler is more than enough.

Comment: the scheduler is not more than enough, because again if a call comes in when the launch screen is happening, then your timer may misfire, or you may present the scene in a paused state.  A general rule of thumb is to never use Timer in Sprite Kit